# Argument out of range date Exception for create action but update works just fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form where the user can enter a date (e.g. 03/18/2014):

```
= f.text_field :purchase_date, class: "form-control", placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

When the user submits the form for a new `Inventory` object, I keep getting the error `argument out of range` in my Create action. However, if I already have an existing object and I try to update it, it works just fine. The weird thing is that my puts is not outputting anything in the server logs.

```
def create

  puts "CREATE" # this line is not outputting anything

  purchase_date = inventory_params["purchase_date"].blank? ? Date.today : Date::strptime(inventory_params["purchase_date"], "%m/%d/%Y")

  @inventory = Inventory.create( name: inventory_params["name"],
                          purchase_price: purchase_price,
                          purchase_date: purchase_date,
                          serial: inventory_params["serial"].to_s,
                          description: inventory_params["description"].to_s,
                          product_type: inventory_params["product_type"].to_s,
                          current_location: inventory_params["current_location"].to_s,
                          vendor_id: inventory_params["vendor_id"],
                          team_id: current_team.id)


  redirect_to inventories_path
end

def update

  purchase_date = inventory_params["purchase_date"].blank? ? Date.today : Date::strptime(inventory_params["purchase_date"], "%m/%d/%Y")

  @inventory.update_attributes( name: inventory_params["name"],
                                purchase_price: purchase_price,
                                purchase_date: purchase_date,
                                serial: inventory_params["serial"],
                                description: inventory_params["description"],
                                product_type: inventory_params["product_type"],
                                current_location: inventory_params["current_location"],
                                vendor_id: inventory_params["vendor_id"]
                                )
  redirect_to inventory_path(@inventory)
end

private

def inventory_params
  params.require(:inventory).permit(:purchase_price, :purchase_date, :name, :serial, :description, :product_type, :current_location, :vendor_id)
end
```

I also have CanCan set up, but I don't think that it is affecting it:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    can [:create, :show, :destroy, :edit, :update], User, id: user.id

    can :create, Inventory
    can [:index, :show, :destroy, :edit, :update], Inventory do |inventory|
      user && (inventory.try(:team_id) == user.teams.first.id)
    end

  end
end
```

Does anyone know why I keep getting an exception when I try to create a new instance of `Inventory`?

**Update:** It looks like if I use double digits for my date, it breaks. For example, `3/1/2014` works, but `3/11/2014` breaks...

Comment: What are types of `vendor_id` and `serial` fields? That error could thrown by database maybe? Just like `int` / `bigint` issue? By the way, don't you use strong parameters? Are you sure you receive your form values properly? Especially `inventory_params["purchase_date"]`?

Comment: @scaryguy vendor_id is an int and serial is a string.

Comment: using `puts` for debug purposes is not very useful. I would suggest checking out the `pry` gem (`pry-rails` if in a rails project). It can help you debug a lot better. It will act as a break point for your code and allow you to look at the values of everything in that spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancan was breaking with Rails 4.0.
This fixed the issue:

`load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:create]`

Comment: I was also running into an issue where CanCanCan was failing over a datetime value that I was processing in my controller before saving.  I ended up using a before_filter to process the value before running CanCan on it, and this resolved the issue and allowed me to run CanCan on create.

Answer (score 1):

Just for you to write less lines next time. What you wrote is equivalent to @inventory =

```
Inventory.create(inventory_params.merge({team_id: current_team.id}))
```

And

```
@inventory.update_attributes(inventory_params)
```

Also, I found your error, you wrote 03/18/14 (That means 2003-18-14), there is no month 18 !
It is not written in the French standard :)

By the way, if you need to use the french (or similar) standard : read that 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

And download the necessary files there:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/fr.yml

Comment: I have `"%m/%d/%Y"`, so shouldn't `03/18/2014` work?

Comment: I don't think I'm using the french standard. If I tried `18/03/2014`, then I get invalid date exception.

Comment: Where do you have that `"%m/%d/%Y"` ? To check if it is working, try 
`Time.parse "03/18/2014"` in your rails console.

Comment: `purchase_date = inventory_params["purchase_date"].blank? ? Date.today : Date::strptime(inventory_params["purchase_date"], "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Yes, that's what I tell you ! The french standard is dd/mm/yyyy. The international (default) one is yyyy/mm/dd.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. I don't want the French standard. I want month/date/year, so that was why I have `%m/%d/%Y`

Comment: Shit, I figured it out. Cancan was breaking it.

Comment: My bad ! I'll try to find another answer

Comment: By the way, what is purchase_price ? isn't is empty ?

Comment: I was able to fix it. Thanks for your help. `purchase_price` isn't empty. I just removed it to simplify the code.